# Ajax not working on mobile devices with Opera 8 mini

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, desktop

The issue is that the ajax script is working on desktop browsers but on mobile devices its not working it just reloads the page.

Here is the script

```
     /* validation */
 $("#login-form").validate({
  rules:
  {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        pass_key: {
            required: true
        }
   },
   messages:
   {

        email: "please enter a valid email address",
        pass_key: "No password given"
   },
   submitHandler: submitForm    
   });  
   /* validation */

   /* submiting data */
   function submitForm()
   {        
       var datta = $("#login-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'actions/login.php',
        data : datta,
        beforeSend: function()
        {   
            $("#feed-back").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-login").html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> &nbsp; loading ...');
        },
        success :  function(resp)
           {                        
                if(resp == 1){
                    $("#feed-back").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                        $("#field-place").fadeOut(800);
                    $("#btn-login").html('<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> &nbsp; Done ...');
                   setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard/index.php"; ',900);
                    });
                }
                else if(resp == 2){
                    $("#feed-back").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                        $("#field-place").fadeOut(800);
                    $("#btn-login").html('<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> &nbsp; Done ...');
                   setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard/admin.php"; ',900);
                    });
                }
                else{

                    $("#feed-back").fadeIn(1000, function(){

            $("#feed-back").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+resp+'! </div>');
                                        $("#btn-login").html('<i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp; Login');

                                });
                }
          }
        });
            return false;
    }
});
```

It also doesn't work on Opera mini 8. It does only reload the page when I submit.

Comment: Does your code work when you try your code on different mobile browser like chrome, safari, etc.?

Comment: yes it does work on chome, safari and firefox

Comment: Headline updated.

Comment: thanks for  your help guys. I have tackled the issue its now working.

Comment: You can answer your own question. After 24h then you can this answer mark as accept. The answer maybe helps other visitors with same or similar problems in the furture.